# When is the Carathéodory sigma-algebra of $\mathcal A$ equal to the generated sigma-algebra $\sigma(\mathcal A)$?

Tags: measure-theory

Given a set $X$ and an algebra of sets $\mathcal A\subset 2^X,$ denote by $\mu$ its algebra measure and $\mu^*$ the outer measure defined on $2^X$ via $\mu$. The Carathéodory sigma-algebra $\mathcal A^*$ is given by all the sets $E\subset X$ such that $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(E\cap A) + \mu^*(A\setminus E)$ for all $A\subset X$. By the Carathéodory theorem, we know that $\mathcal A^*$ is a sigma-algebra which contains $\mathcal A$ and $\mu^*|_{\mathcal A^*}$ is actually a sigma-algebra measure.

Since $\mathcal A\subset \mathcal A^*,$ it follows that $\sigma(\mathcal A) \subset \mathcal A^*$, where by $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ we denote the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal A$.

**What I want to know is**:  when  $\mathcal A^* = \sigma(\mathcal A)$? What are some good examples of this phenomena?

It seems that there is actually no general criteria which can state when $\mathcal A^* = \mathcal A;$ not even when $\mathcal A$ itself is a sigma-algebra it follows, since we can always take a sigma-algebra $\mathcal A$  which is not the power set of $X$ with the null measure and the Caratheodory sigma-algebra $\mathcal A^*$ thus obtained will always be $2^X$.

Until now the only (*trivial)* example that I found was  $\mathcal A = 2^X$, because by definition $\mathcal A^* \subset 2^X.$

Comment: Looking at the usual Lebesgue measure construction, if $\mathcal{A}$ are the "rectangles", $\mathcal{A}^*$ will be the completness of $\sigma ( \mathcal{A} )$. So I guess (a proof would be needed) that if $\sigma ( \mathcal{A} )$ is complete, they are the same. That would be true if $\mathcal{A}$ has the sets that generate all subsets of null sets.